# How to get the return's value of asynchronous function?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, asynchronous

I want to get the return's value of asynchronous function as an array when i *console* that function's name. What i got before was an object.

1) What i have wrote in my controller :

```
$scope.allBrands = function(){

      var brands = [];

      return BrandService.get().then(function(data) {

           angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
             return brands.push(value.name);
           });

           return brands;

     });
};

console.log($scope.allBrands());
```

2) The result of console.log($scope.allBrands()) :

```
f
      $$state: Object
        status: 1
        value: Array[33]
          0: "ALAIA"
          1: "ALBERTA FERRETTI"
          2: "Alessandra Rich"
          3: "Alexander Mcqueen"
          4: "Alexander Wang"
          5: "Alice + Olivia"
          6: "Amanda Wakeley"
          7: "Balenciaga"
          8: "Bcbg Maxazria"
          9: "Bcbg Maz Azria"
          10: "Biyan"
          11: "Burberry"
          12: "Calvin Klein"
          13: "Casadei"
          14: "Chanel"
          15: "Charlotte Olympia"
          16: "Chloe"
          17: "Christian Dior"
          18: "Dolce & Gabbana"
          19: "Emilia Wickstead"
          20: "Farah Khan"
          21: "Fendi"
          22: "Gucci"
          23: "Halston Heritage"
          24: "Herve Leger"
          25: "Lanvin"
          26: "Louis Leeman"
          27: "Mary Katrantzou"
          28: "Roberto Cavalli"
          29: "Sebastian Gunawan"
          30: "Self-Portrait"
          31: "Valentino"
          32: "Versace"
         length: 
        __proto__: Array[0]
       __proto__: Object
      __proto__: Object
```

3) The result i would like to achieve :

```
["ALAIA", "ALBERTA FERRETTI", "Alessandra Rich", "Alexander Mcqueen", "Alexander Wang", "Alice + Olivia", "Amanda Wakeley", "Balenciaga", "Bcbg Maxazria", "Bcbg Maz Azria", "Biyan", "Burberry", "Calvin Klein", "Casadei", "Chanel", "Charlotte Olympia", "Chloe", "Christian Dior", "Dolce & Gabbana", "Emilia Wickstead", "Farah Khan", "Fendi", "Gucci", "Halston Heritage", "Herve Leger", "Lanvin", "Louis Leeman", "Mary Katrantzou", "Roberto Cavalli", "Sebastian Gunawan", "Self-Portrait", "Valentino", "Versace"]
```

Can anyone point me out how should it be done ?

---

*EDIT

**This is the solution** :

```
$scope.allBrands = function(){    
   var brands = [];
   return BrandService.get().then(function(data) {      
       angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
           brands.push(value.name);
       });
       return brands;
   });
};

var promise = $scope.allBrands(); 

promise.then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
},
function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.allBrands()))`.

Comment: You cannot. It's asynchronous. Use the promise it returns: `$scope.allBrands().then(console.log)`

Comment: @RobG it's not work. This is the result  {"$$state":{"status":0}}

Comment: @Bergi .. i dont understand what is the point of  `then(console.log)`

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution Well, you wanted to log the result - `console.log($scope.allBrands());` doesn't work, it logs the promise only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous call doesn't work the way you are thinking(synchronous way). They doesn't return a value as soon as server you call them. You have to wait till server respond to request.

Over here as you did `console.log` the `allBrands` function which return `promise` object(seems like `$resource` promise), that is getting consoled. And you can see your response in the promise object as soon as it arrives. I'd say you should use `.then` over your promise object where you can just get a data returned from API.

```
$scope.allBrands().then(successCB(states){
   $scope.states = states;
   console.log(states);
}, errorCB(error){
   console.log(error)
})
```

Comment: can you tell me where i put those code above ?
i'm sorry .. i am new to this AngularJS

Comment: @RidoanSalehNasution inside your controller.. there you could assign it to `$scope` as well to use it on HTML view

Answer (score 0):

You don't should return the promise, instead you can return a new array inside the resolve function:

```
$scope.allBrands = function(){
  BrandService.get().then(function(data) {
       return data.map(function(item) { return item.name })
  });
};
```

Comment: OP already doing that thing, he is returning `brands` correctly, this is not what OP is asking for..